# Failed to bootstrap model, cannot start Juju bootstrap instance

Tags: ubuntu, openstack, juju

I am currently following the guide from [Openstack.org](https://docs.openstack.org/project-deploy-guide/charm-deployment-guide/latest/install-juju.html)
and have deployed the MAAS and Juju on 2 virtual machines (in VirtualBox).

However, at the below step, I get the following error and I'm not sure where the problem is:

```
juju bootstrap --constraints tags=juju mymaas maas-controller
```

Error:

```
Creating Juju controller "maas-controller" on mymaas
Looking for packaged Juju agent version 2.3.8 for amd64
No packaged binary found, preparing local Juju agent binary
Launching controller instance(s) on mymaas... 
ERROR failed to bootstrap model: cannot start bootstrap instance: failed to acquire node: unexpected : ServerError: 400 Bad Request ({"tags": ["No such tags(s): 'juju'."]})
```

Comment: Just wanted to know, once you discover the nodes in maas, you need to add the proper tags and then commission the node on MAAS. Were you able to discover and commission ? once you see that node with juju tag is ready then you need to do bootstrap.

Comment: Yes, basically that is what I did.

Comment: but as per the error there is no node with tag juju...can you check if the juju node that you commissioned has juju tag ?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you must have used something like VirtualBox or similar. Check the network settings. Did you use NAT? If yes, then this might be the source of your problem, which is that Juju isn't reachable. It may be listening somewhere without being available. So if the setting is NAT, then put it to Bridge, so that it appears within your LAN as any other machine, requesting an IP from your DHCP. Read more on that [here](https://www.opentechguides.com/how-to/article/virtualbox/140/vm-virtualbox-networking.html).

Check then if it works. If it still doesn't work, then check the firewalls within your concerned systems. The settings will be done through `ufw`. Check out how to do that [here](https://www.linode.com/docs/security/firewalls/configure-firewall-with-ufw/).

Comment: The juju has 2 interfaces, 1 is NAT to connect to internet, and the other is internal (and it can successful ping MAAS server)

Comment: Where is the juju packaged binary supposed to be ?

Comment: It's difficult for mee to guess about your setup. NAT can be problematic, depending on the setup. The reason is that it translates the IPs. Better give your VMs full network access by Bridging them. Also you may want to double check you installation here: https://docs.jujucharms.com/2.3/en/reference-install

Comment: Another thing, the guide you're using is meant for Ubuntu 16.04. Did you use the same Ubuntu version for your VMs?

Comment: Well i tired it both with 16.04, and 18 and have the same problem..